# Passing variables containing urls in Jade Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, template-engine

I am having trouble displaying a link correctly in Jade when I pass in an object.

```
// Story object

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55db6e1710976558828f8053"),
    "author" : ObjectId("55d7a215a3695c620c586f12"),
    "link" : "benjelnews.com",
    "title" : "hello",
    "updated" : ISODate("2015-08-24T19:18:47.589Z"),
    "created" : ISODate("2015-08-24T19:18:47.589Z"),
    "comments" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
}
// App.js

res.render('news', {data: story});

// News.jade

a(href=data.link)=data.title
```

However, the link keeps showing up as "localhost:4000/benjelnews.com"
Can someone explain why my local server address keeps showing and how I can properly configure my Express or Jade template to display the correct format which is just "benjelnews.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade renders your template to this HTML:

```
<a href="benjelnews.com">hello</a>
```

Since `benjelnews.com` is not a valid URL (it doesn't start with a scheme, like `http://` or `https://`), your browser interprets that as a relative path on your local webserver (which apparently is running on `http://localhost:4000`).

If all your links look like that, you can add the scheme in your template:

```
a(href = 'http://' + data.link)= data.title
```

(and hope that all links are plain HTTP and not HTTPS)

Ideally, your database should contain proper URL's.